# Color map using list and if/else in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, visualization

I'm trying to extend the simple example given in Mike Bostock's [Let's Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) to allow coloring countries in a map based on whether their name appears in a list.

How do I color Scotland and Wales green and the other countries blue if I've defined a list `var selected_countries = ["SCT", "WLS"]`?

The following code works for coloring just one country (Scotland) using a conditional if/else statement, but how do I extend this to change the class of all those countries listed in the variable `selected_countries`?  I've tried `if(selected_countries.contains(d.id))...` but this doesn't work, I'm guessing the scoping is what's tripping me up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
.subunit.selected { fill: green; }
.subunit.not-selected { fill: grey; }
</style>

<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * 5)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var selected_countries = ["SCT", "WLS"]

d3.json("uk.json", function(error, uk) {
  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
    .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { 
        if (d.id == "SCT") {return "subunit selected"}
        else {return "subunit not-selected"};
      })
    .attr("d", path);
});
</script>
```

Comment: try something like `if(selected_countries.indexOf(d.id)>-1)`, I think it should dothe trick

Comment: That definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two (at least) ways to do this:

1. Have a variable named "blue" or whatever color you want other countries to have. Then use a `for loop` that goes through all the elements in the list. At each iteration of `for loop`, make a comparative statement to check if your `d.id == <current element in list>` or not. Something like:

   ```
   var color = 'blue';         // or subunit not-selected
   for (var i=0; i<lengthOf(selected_countries); i++)
   {
       if (d.id == selected_countries[i])
           color = 'green';    // or subunit selected
   }
   return color;
   ```
2. You can use the indexOf() method that returns '-1' when the parameter passed is not in the list.

   ```
   ((selected_countries.indexOf(d.id) == -1) ? return blue : return green);
   ```